# Twilio Conference - Record the Conference in the middle of the Call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-conference

I am developing a conference application using Twilio. I need to record the conference but not from the start. Whenever I need to record I should be able to record the conference. It is mostly in the middle of the call. For example like I am having a call with 3-4 other participants and maybe after 10 or 15 minutes, I will need to start recording the call. I checked Twilio `conference-updater` and `participant-updater` but I didn't find any way to record the call. So if I use the Twilio `call-updater` and pass `Twiml with Record` (I saw Record is a one-way recording) will it work and record the whole conference or will it only record one person (owner of that call sid) voice? Or else is there another cleaner approach to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conference Recording Controls](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010199074-Getting-Started-with-Call-Recording-Controls)

Conference recordings can be paused and resumed in the same way as regular calls. The only difference is instead of making your HTTP POST requests to the active call’s subresources, your requests would go to the active conference’s subresources.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and putting your time to answer for this question. But I have another small question, to start the recording we need to pass the `CallSid` but to pause the conference it asks for the `ConferenceSid`. So is there a way we can start the recording by passing just the `ConferenceSid` instead of `CallSid`?

Comment: Don’t quite understand your question, I see this on the docs: “ Notice: Initiating a conference recording needs to be requested in the TwiML <Conference> noun attributes, and is not supported via the Call Recording Controls API. ”

Comment: Actually, I go through SDK samples [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording?code-sample=code-create-recording-on-a-live-call&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json). So according to the samples when creating a recording I need to pass `CallSid`. But [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording?code-sample=code-pause-a-conference-recording-with-skip-option&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json) to pause the conference I need to pass the `ConferenceSid`. So I was wondering is there a way to create the recording with `ConferenceSid` instead of `CallSid`?